# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined : Can not call my function with onclick button [solved]

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have got the weird errors from browser when I was trying to add individual events to each buttons that I have created in table.
It has never happened before till now. Can someone tell me where is my blind spot? thanks

**Here is how I generate the table with callback function from response data:**

```
$("#bulletin .card-body tbody").html("")
$.each(data.content, function(index, item){
  var type = $("#bulletin .card-header button").eq(item.type-1).text()
  var res = 
   '<tr>'+
    '<td>'+parseInt(index+1)+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+item.announcement+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+type+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+item.announcement+'</td>'+
    '<td>'+item.createdTime+'</td>'+
   '<td><button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="openBulletinDetails(\'' + item.id + '\')">details</button</td>'+
  '</tr>';
 $("#bulletin .card-body tbody").append(res)
})
```

**And there you go the callback:**

```
function openBulletinDetails(id){
  console.log(id)
}
```

**I can only got this error**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: openBulletinDetails is not defined

**I request the data from restful API using ajax to get that JSON if it helps.**

```
function generateTable(){   
  // XHR
  $.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + globalAuthToken);
     },
     success: function(data) {
         // generate the table here....
     },
     error: function(data) {
        alert(data.status);
     }
  });  
}
function openBulletinDetails(id){
  console.log(id)
}
```

**Problem solved!!!**

The reason why I got this error is because >> **I set my external js file as module type.** None of logic were wrong. But why is that stopping the onclick events? no clue...if anyone knows the reason, kindly give me some response.

Comment: Hi, where is that function located ?

Comment: @Swati Hi, the callback just locate right after ajax function. I have updated the quiz.

Comment: just for test put that function before ajax call see what happens .

Comment: You probbaly have the function wrapped by a function (aka document ready?)

Comment: @epascarello The ajax function was called in $(function() { generateTable() }) , I thought the document had fully loaded?

Comment: @Swati Yes. I did that too, The callback name did not light up in IDE.

Comment: I set my external js file as module type causing all these problems